# Alpha channel in colortbl

Tags: tables, color, transparency, colortbl

I'm using the `colortbl` package to color table cells.  I've combined this w/ the `xcolor` package to define my own colors.  However, it appears that `xcolor` does not support transparency.  I saw the package `transparent`, but it is oriented toward text and I wasn't able to set the transparency level of a defined color.  Are there any packages that support alpha color channels?

Comment: You could do that either with PSTricks or with PGF/TikZ. A similar problem was discussed here: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=697

Comment: Yes, I saw that page, it doesn't really seem to address my question.  Does anyone know how I could use TikZ to do this?  I'd like to stick w/ pdflatex.

Comment: http://texblog.net/latex-archive/graphics/tikz-table/

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one as well, but he does not actually color cells in that table using TikZ as far as I can see.  He uses colortbl which to the best of my knowledge doesn't accept colors w/ alpha channels

Comment: For clarification of the posted question.

Do you want to change the color of individual cells in a tabular, where the new colors can be semi transparent?

Comment: midtiby, exactly!

Comment: colortbl doesn't really care (much) what the color command is it just arranges to put a normal TeX rule behind the table cell and inser a "colour command" at suitable points to affect the color. so basically if tikz or pstricks or anything allows you to define a transparent colour such that (say) `\color{something}\hrule` makes a rule of transparent colour `something` then the same shoud work in colortbl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following shows `colortbl` transparent panels allowing the coloured box behind the table to show through.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{transparent,colortbl}


\makeatletter
\def\CT@@do@color{%
  \global\let\CT@do@color\relax
        \@tempdima\wd\z@
        \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimb
        \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimc
        \kern-\@tempdimb
\transparent{0.6}%
        \leaders\vrule
                \hskip\@tempdima\@plus  1fill
        \kern-\@tempdimc
        \hskip-\wd\z@ \@plus -1fill }
\makeatother

\begin{document}






\noindent\colorbox[rgb]{1,.5,.5}{\Large\strut \hspace{2in}}\hspace{-.5in}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\rowcolor{blue} a & b & c\\
                aa&bb&cc\\
\rowcolor{yellow}1&2&3\\
                11&22&33
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this workaround doesn't work with tabularx

Comment: Why does this workaround not work with XeLaTeX?

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs no idea:-) Does transparency work at all in xetex?

Answer (score 2):

For information, `nicematrix` provides a key `opacity` in its tools dealing with color (within its own environments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent\colorbox[rgb]{1,.5,.5}{\Large\strut \hspace{5cm}}\hspace{-2cm}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,color-inside]{ccc}
\rowcolor[opacity=0.5]{yellow} one & two & three \\
\Block[fill=blue,opacity=0.5]{2-2}{}
four & five & six \\
seven & eight & nine
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]