# Why does transparent not work well in XeLaTeX and how can I fix it?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I'm looking for a semi transparent black background on certain table rows in a pdf document.

I have tried to apply
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62528/23302
and it works if I use pdflatex. But I have to use XeLaTeX; however, it produces error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\CT@do@color ...mc \kern -\@tempdimb \transparent
                                                  {0.5}\leaders \vrule \hski...
l.36 \rowcolor{black}Date &
                            Value\tabularnewline
```

My tex file is:

```
%% LyX 2.0.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{transparent,colortbl}

\makeatletter
\def\CT@@do@color{%
  \global\let\CT@do@color\relax
        \@tempdima\wd\z@
        \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimb
        \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimc
        \kern-\@tempdimb
\transparent{0.5}%
        \leaders\vrule
                \hskip\@tempdima\@plus  1fill
        \kern-\@tempdimc
        \hskip-\wd\z@ \@plus -1fill }
\makeatother

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\rowcolor{black}Date & Value\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
Nov & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
Jun & 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
Apr & 3\tabularnewline
\hline 
Jan & 4\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `transparent` package makes a fairly clear warning: `Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in 
PDF mode.` so the problem is unrelated to tables/colortbl you need to find an implementation of transparency that works with xetex, so depends on the capability of the `xdvipdfmx` dvi driver, mostly